# Python exact pattern matches using re.search

Tags: python, search

I want to search exact  search for  stop_enabc on file  but my code returns stop_enabcc also if file has this stop_enabcc

```
    search_term ="stop_enabc"
    f = "C:/Users/test.txt"
    result=search(f,search)
    print result

def search(f,search):

    for line in open(f, 'r'):
        if re.search(search, line):
           return line
```

Input sample:

```
test.txt

stop_enabc

xxxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyyyystop_enabccc
stop_enabccc
```

Comment: Provide your sample input file..and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
re.search(r"^stop_enabc$", line)
```